# Clipping ggplot2 map by longitude R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalt

I want to make a map of the Eastern U.S., however only within the longitude range of -95 degrees to -66.5 degrees I've started using `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
us_map <- map_data('usa')
map <- ggplot(data=us_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + geom_polygon(fill = 'black')
map
```

which generates this map:
[image]

I would like to clip the map to only -95 degrees to -66.5 degrees. I used to do this with the `coord_proj` function within `ggalt` package like this:

```
map <- map + coord_proj("+proj=cea +lat_ts=37.5",ylim = c(25,50), xlim = c(-95,-66.5)) #crib map to eastern US.
```

However this now throws the error, `Error: Not implemented`.

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe using sf: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/371960/61922

Comment: Try using `+ coord_fixed(xlim=c(-95, -66.5))`. For me, this worked.

Comment: @Zoe this works, but for some reason also adds a bunch of white space once I make a multi-panel figure with `ggarrange()`.

Comment: I think you might be able to handle this by giving a diferent ratio? Like `coord_fixed(1.5, xlim=c(-95, -66.5))`. The deafult is 1. (I plotted two maps next to each other and for me, it looks okay? Maybe you also have to adjust the `ggarrange()` arguments `width` and `height`?)

Comment: @Zoe that was the answer! Thank you!